# Exclude Two Parents get_the_terms

Tags: php

This should be pretty straight forward and I'm looking forward to learning how to do it.

The code below excludes the top level parent only. How do I modify this code to exclude the next level down as well?

EG:

My hierarchical terms are World>Country>USA

I'd like to display USA and not World or Country

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'From' );

if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

    $output = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ){

        if( 0 != $term->parent )
            $output[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) .'">' . $term->name . '</a>';

    }

    if( count( $output ) )
        echo '' . __('Categories:','om_theme') . '</b> ' . join( ", ", $output ) . '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '' . __('Categories:','om_theme') . '</b> ' . end($output) . '';
```

Comment: Please also briefly explain the code to be more educative.